# Reference variable returning error "No longer attached to the DOM" while the actual command line is working

Tags: java, selenium

So i have a line in my code that goes like this

```
 WebElement docDate = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("html/body/div[5]/div/div/form/div/div[4]/div[1]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/input")));
 docDate.sendKeys(date);.
```

The first time this runs it is working well. The second time I use `docDate.sendKeys` though it, it is returning an error `Element is no longer attached to the DOM`. However, if I write the whole statement again (exactly the statement i used above) i no longer encounter the error. It's like I can't use the reference, but if I write the whole wait.until line it is working without any issues, and it's the same damn line. Any idea/explanation for why this is happening?

Answer (score 3):

It happens because element you found before changes, even it has same xpath.
Try to use wait with Expectedconditions.stalenessOf() and old element

Comment: StalenessOf() looks to be a boolean method, i can't use sendKeys with that

Comment: you can write method to wrap this. 1) Wait until element visible - send keys 2) Wait until element staleness 3) Find element again.

Comment: Hey Nick, i now got this error when using staleness:`Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up` - any ideas?